# A question about an LQP audit - Too helpful comment?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

There is an answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492897/mobile-phone-protocols) in the LQP queue as audit. I don't know if the link works but here it is [for the audit answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11455404).

Actually the answer is obviously spam but the comment is very handy for such an audit:

> Click flag, then spam, then validate, and make Stack Overflow a better place.

That's a really easy audit. Maybe a bit to easy with that comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Audits are meant to be a low hurdle to get over to prove that you're not robo-clicking.  Robo-clickers don't bother to read such comments anyway.

The comment did, however, have the effect of making *you* think, "Hmm..."

[Mission accomplished](https://xkcd.com/810/).